# In Bash, how can I run multiple infinitely-running commands and cancel them all with ^C?

Tags: bash, process, signals

I would like to write a script that runs a few different infinitely running commands, e.g.

```
run_development_webserver.sh
watch_sass_files_and_compile_them.sh
watch_coffeescript_files_and_compile_them.sh
```

I'd like to run each of them in parallel, and kill them all by hitting ^C. Is this possible, and if so how can I do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'll let Admiral Ackbar answer this one.

[image: trap]

```
#!/bin/bash -e

run_development_webserver.sh &
PIDS[0]=$!
watch_sass_files_and_compile_them.sh &
PIDS[1]=$!
watch_coffeescript_files_and_compile_them.sh & 
PIDS[2]=$!

trap "kill ${PIDS[*]}" SIGINT

wait
```

This starts each of your commands in the background (`&`), puts their process ids (`$!`) into an array (`PIDS[x]=$!`), tells `bash` to `kill` them all (`${PIDS[*]`) when your script gets a `SIGINT` signal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), and then `wait`s for all the processes to exit.

And I'll proactively mention that `"kill ${PIDS[*]}"` expands `PIDS` when you create the `trap`; if you change the double quotes (`"`) to single quotes (`'`), it will be expanded when the `trap` is executed, which means you can add more processes to `PIDS` after you set the `trap` and it will kill them too.

If you have a stubborn process that doesn't want to quit after a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (`SIGINT`), you may need to send it a stronger kill signal - `SIGTERM` or even `SIGKILL` (use this as a last resort, it unconditionally kills the process without giving it a chance to clean up).  First, try changing the `trap` line to this:

```
trap "kill -TERM ${PIDS[*]}" SIGINT
```

If it doesn't respond to the `SIGTERM`, save that process's pid separately, say in `STUBBORN_PID`, and use this:

```
trap "kill ${PIDS[*]}; kill -KILL $STUBBORN_PID" SIGINT
```

Remember, this one won't let the stubborn process clean up, but if it needs to die and isn't, you may need to use it anyway.

Comment: Quick, image macro, _and_ the right answer? **Commence upvoting.**

Comment: I +1'd because this seems to be the generally right answer. However one of the scripts (actually starting memcached not in daemon mode) seems to catch the ^C itself and trying to kill it later fails. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @RuddZwolinski You may need a stronger kill signal for that process. I've added some bits on that, try those.

Comment: @Kevin Good addition, but my problem is that `memcached` seems to override the trap and catch `^C` itself as well; by the time I try to kill it, it's already shut itself down.

Comment: @RuddZwolinski So if it shuts itself down fairly quickly, what exactly is the problem? It probably needs that time to save whatever data it needs and exit gracefully. Is the bash script not exiting? I'd think it ought to because it's just `wait`ing for its children to exit.

Comment: @Kevin I can special-case it (by just not adding its pid to `$PIDS`), so it's not a problem; just wondering why trap doesn't hide it.

Comment: @RuddZwolinski (Mostly from your situation,) I would guess that signals received are passed to child processes first, to let them know the parent received the signal and they may be killed or orphaned.